# why cant i see the decimal point numbers in c#?

Tags: c#

```
int total = 201;

double Average = total / 7;

result should be 28.71428571428571.
```

I've tried float, decimal and double for Average but the result ends up as 28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `D` suffix to implicitly state the operand is a double, for example:

```
201 / 7
28

201 / 7D
28.714285714285715
```

Or:

```
double Average = total / 7D;
```

Answer (score 11):

You are doing integer division!

`201/7` is entirely integral, and so the result doesn't even touch floats, instead you need to cast to a double first:

```
double Average = (double)total / 7.0;
```

Comment: the cast is no needed if you use a double literal (7.0)

Comment: @Stilgar, I included both as that's what I usually do in code. It makes the whole operation very clear to anyone reading. Then again, that is my personal style.

Answer (score 2):

It's doing integer arithmetic, because total is an int, and 7 is an int. If you change either of them to decimal you'll get the result you're looking for.

e.g.

```
int total = 201;

double Average = total / 7.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because an int divided by an int is always an int.

try this:

```
double average = total / 7.0;
```

Comment: the cast is no needed if you use a double literal (7.0)

Answer (score 1):

the total is int and 7 is int. The resul of integer division is int. It gets cast AFTER that to double but this does not matter because it is already truncated. Try:

```
double average = total / 7.0;
```

7.0 is a double literal and the result of int and double division is double.